# Attempting to debug seemingly correct line of HTML in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, syntax, internet-explorer-10

The following snippet is from my login page for my web application:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘PK Store Scrollup’, ‘Clicked’]);" class="scrollup" >Scroll</a>
```

There isn't an error reported by any other browser however IE10 is listing 3 warnings and an error. I'm focused on the error right now which is as followed:

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
login, line 664 character 38
```

Including soft spacing at the beginning of the line, "character 38" seems to be the **[‘** at the beginning of _trackEvent. Do these need to be switched to single quotes? Any recommendations?

Comment: Try using `'` single quotes instead.

Comment: Try: <a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PK Store Scrollup', 'Clicked']);" class="scrollup" >Scroll</a>  (I replaced the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing those `‘` and `’` into regular single quotes `'`.

Comment: Guess I should've put my comment as an answer =D

Comment: Yes, but then you wouldn't have exactly 10000 rep anymore :)

Comment: Thank you! I probably should have just tried single quotes but it came directly from Google's documentation so I assumed it infallible but now I see the light.